# Is there a way to remove the font weight on this custom font?

Tags: css, fonts

Hi so I just imported this font from https://fonts.google.com and I can't seem to remove the font weight setting, I've tried removing the weight thing from the URL and nothing helps

`@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300&display=swap');`

Comment: could you add a snippet to show your trouble or are we supposed to build a sample to find out what you mean ? Help us to help you. thank you buddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each weight you have to load its own font. In your question it is

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@200;300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

This will load 2 fonts, in weight 200 and weight 300. After that, you can use it in your custom styling, for example

```
h2 {
  font-family: Montserrat, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 200;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css  `font-weight` property.
Check this https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_weight.asp